# How do I use and administrative form and save a message?

Tags: 8, forms

I followed the instructions on [Step by step guide to creating an admin form in Drupal 8](https://befused.com/drupal/drupal8-admin-form-guide).

I typed in a welcome text into the admin form and saved it, but after saving the form was empty again.

I am new to Drupal and php and don't know yet how to debug the code. I can not use Php-Storm because it is too expensive. Therefore I am using Visual Studio.

The website and database are running inside Docker. I mounted the folder for the modules, so I can write the module code from outside docker. I am working on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

This is the whole class:

```
namespace Drupal\welcome\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class MessagesForm extends ConfigFormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
    return [
      'welcome.adminsettings',
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormID() {
    return 'welcome_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->config('hello_world.adminsettings');

    $form['welcome_message'] = [
      '#type'          => 'textarea',
      '#title'         => $this->t('Willkommens Nachricht'),
      '#description'   => $this->t('Willkommens Nachricht, die beim Anmelden erscheint.'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('welcome_message'),
    ];

    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);

    $this->config('welcome.adminsettings')
      ->set('welcome_message', $form_state->getValue('welcome_message'))
      ->save();
  }
}
```

I just learned how to inpect variables with ksm() and found that the value is stored in the welcome_message variable.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It's hard to answer your question in its current form. Maybe you can provide some more information? First of all, tell us what you did to debug this. How do you know the value "vanishes"? Did you check that `submitForm()` is actually being called? If so, does $form_state contain the expected value? Also, please update your question to show us the entire form class (MessagesForm.php), because the problem might not be where you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I found the bug.

In buildForm is says:

```
hello_world.adminsettings
```

But it must be:

```
 welcome.adminsettings
```